# Instagram real-time api

Tags: real-time, instagram-api

I'm trying to use [Instagram real-time api](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)  but I can't make it work. I created an express.js server that responds to challenge verification on subscription creation. I get a json response with my subscription details and I can list my current subscriptions from Instagram API.

Everything works ... except I don't get a POST request. Any idea?

Regards!

Comment: i have some problem too, can some one give an example ?

Comment: Seeing same issue -- did you ever resolve this?

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Answer (score -1):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var request = require('request');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var CLIENT_ID ='';
var CLIENT_SECRET = '';
var CALLBACK_URL = 'http://website.com/subscribe';

app.get('/:object/:object_id', function (req, res) {
    var object = req.params.object;
    var object_id = req.params.object_id;

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        request.post('https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/', {form: {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            aspect: 'media',
            object: object,
            object_id: object_id,
            callback_url: CALLBACK_URL
        }});

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            request.del('https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET+'&object=all&client_id='+CLIENT_ID)
        });
    });

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
})

app.get('/subscribe', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
});

app.post('/subscribe', function (req, res) {
    io.emit('message', JSON.stringify(req.body));
})

http.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>htag</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="stream"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io(window.location.origin);
      socket.on('message', function (text) {
        $('#stream').prepend('<p>' + text);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you just dumping a giant block of code without any explanation?

Comment: @ceejayoz what explanation? This is working example. Do I need to comment every line of **a giant** html?

Comment: It's entirely unclear why you think this giant block of code/HTML is likely to solve the OP's problem. OP states that they're not receiving POST calls after successfully creating a subscription.

Comment: Few people in comments asked for example. OP problems is either in code or in enviroment. If it's latter it's not stackoverflow question. So my code is 100% likely to solve the OP's problem as it is complete working example able to eliminate one of the suspects.